# Max function not working in simple sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `per_all_people_f` with 3000-4000 person numbers. A few non-numeric characters are also there in some cases. I want to pick the highest number present in this table. When I am using the below query :

```
select ( MAX ( DISTINCT person_number) ) from per_all_people_f
where REGEXP_LIKE(person_number  , '^[[:digit:]]+$')
```

I am not getting the maximum number. I am getting 98098 although much bigger numbers like -1503388 already exist in the system.
 How can I change the above query to get the maximum "Number" in this column.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `distinct` doesn't really make sense together with `max()`

Answer (score 5):

You need to convert to a number.  Otherwise the `max()` is as a string:

```
select MAX(TO_NUMBER(person_number))
from per_all_people_f
where REGEXP_LIKE(person_number, '^[[:digit:]]+$')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is conversion issue. You can use below method for conversion:

using `CAST`:

```
select MAX(CAST(person_number as NUMBER))
from per_all_people_f
where REGEXP_LIKE(person_number, '^[[:digit:]]+$')
```

or using `TO_NUMBER` :

```
select 
max(TO_NUMBER(person_number))
from per_all_people_f
where 
REGEXP_LIKE(person_number, '^[[:digit:]]+$')
```